# BeautifulSoup fails parsing when it hits an unescaped bracket

Tags: python, parsing, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble loading a page which has a literal (unescaped) email tag in it, such as

```
<html>
    <head>
            <title>Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <p>Testing testing.</p>
            <p>This is an email address for <joe@somewhere.com></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Parsing fails when it hits that block:

File "/tools/oss/packages/x86_64-rhel5/python/2.7.1/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 115, in error
    raise HTMLParseError(message, self.getpos())
HTMLParseError: malformed start tag, at line 748, column 82

I can't believe I'm the first one to hit this, but I can't immediately find any help or useful documentation. Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks,

-- 
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Always the way - when you post a question you suddenly find the answer afterwards.

It looks like I hit the bug described in http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=516824 - updating to a later BeautifulSoup does indeed fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, I was about to post a CANNOTREPRODUCE comment with version 3.2.0 here. :)

Answer (score -1):

This is a common issue with the BeautifulSoup. 
It doesn't handle the malformed tags since it uses regex to detect the tags.

Try lxml for python. It is worth it, considering it is similar to BeautifulSoup.

http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html

PS: Updating BeautifulSoup also might help it.